# Need help envisioning how to move cable from wall to ceiling

Tags: wiring, drywall, walls, ceiling, ethernet

Location: U.S.

I have a series of wireless access points in the home that are currently wall mounted. For best coverage, I want to ceiling mount them instead. What do I need in order to do this?

**I need help envisioning how to get from the single gang wall box behind the access point up to the new single gang cutout I plan to install in the ceiling. If I need to drill through studs/joists, how many am I drilling through?**

Black square is roughly where I’ll cut out the new single gang.

[image]

What I think I need:

- Drywall saw
- Flexible drill bit (?)
- Cable fish to somehow get cable from existing wall location to new ceiling
- Ethernet cable to extend wall jack to ceiling

Comment: do the APs use PoE? (power over ethernet) ... how many cables are connected to the AP?

Comment: How is moving them 10 inches improving the coverage ?

Comment: Are you sure the coverage will be that much better after doing all this work?

Comment: The access points are PoE with a single cable per AP, no AC power required. The antenna patterns on the APs is more conducive to ceiling mounting than wall mounting.

Comment: ...and yet, a major benefit of proper ceiling mounting you'll not get here is getting them the heck away from the walls. Meanwhile, you are facing a miserable job to try and move them this short distance. If you have any where there's an attic (or similar) access overhead they might be worth moving - as a WiFi & network pro, I would not touch this job into a blind ceiling as described with a 49-1/2 foot pole. Loads of work, very likely little or no measurable benefit.

Comment: Waste of time...multiple access points in a home is overkill in its own right... if your router can't cover your home on its own, get a better router.

Comment: Tahwos - clearly you know nothing about networking. Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: Ecnerwal - why wouldn’t you touch this job?